# Passing file name in Custom Action using WiX

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3.6

I want to pass a file name in the argument of Custom Action. These files are getting installed into the system. Can I pass the component id of these files rather than passing hard coded name?

Answer (score 0):

Since Wix has provided Session variables to communicate with C# custom actions ....assign your files path in some Session variable and use it in custom action...

Make sure that the variable name should be in CAPS